# Cannot redeclare class AbstractFindAdapter

Tags: php, laravel, github

I have an error in my Laravel install that has cropped up [seemingly] intermittently. Its as follows below:

```
[2015-04-22 15:30:45] production.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 'Cannot redeclare class Symfony\Component\Finder\Adapter\AbstractFindAdapter' in /var/www/web/website/htdocs/vendor/symfony/finder/Symfony/Component/Finder/Adapter/AbstractFindAdapter.php:28
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: Illuminate\Exception\Handler->handleShutdown()
#1 {main} [] []
[2015-04-22 15:32:39] production.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 'Cannot redeclare class Symfony\Component\Finder\Adapter\AbstractFindAdapter' in /var/www/web/website/htdocs/vendor/symfony/finder/Symfony/Component/Finder/Adapter/AbstractFindAdapter.php:28
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: Illuminate\Exception\Handler->handleShutdown()
#1 {main} [] []
```

It seems to be coming from the Vendor files, and based on how short the Stack Trace is there isn't a lot for me to do...

I suppose my question isn't "How do I make this work" but more, how do I go about trouble shooting a problem that is likely from someone else repository? Is raising an issue on Github the first port of call or does that error actually contain enough information for me to look into a fix myself?

Comment: It's means you have to use `sudo` , file permission issue.

Comment: It is 100% **not** that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I'm not entirely sure, but I believe* the issue was a corrupt composer install. To fix it I:

1. Deleted the whole vendor directory
2. Ran composer install again